# App not finding GPS signal

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, android-gps

I made a speedometer for my android devices. I used my Samsung Galaxy Tablet to test my app, everything worked perfect. After I finished, I wanted to try it on my phone but couldnt get it working. It shows only "searching gps".. I asked my friend if he could try it on his phone but still the same problem. Does anyone had similar problems? I changed the API level but no difference. Both phones are running the newest android version, but my tablet is running 5.1.1.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationService myService;
static boolean status;
LocationManager locationManager;
static TextView dist, time, speed, timetext, disttext;
static long startTime, endTime;
ImageView image;
static ProgressDialog locate;
static int p = 0;
public SharedPreferences preferences;
public SharedPreferences preferences2;

private ServiceConnection sc = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        LocationService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationService.LocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        status = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        status = false;
    }
};

public ImageButton androidImmageButton;
public void init() {
    androidImmageButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    androidImmageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Einstellungen.class);
            startActivity(toy);
        }
    });
}

void bindService() {
    if (status == true)
        return;
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    bindService(i, sc, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    status = true;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

void unbindService() {
    if (status == false)
        return;
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
    unbindService(sc);
    status = false;
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (status == true)
        unbindService();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    if (status == false)
        super.onBackPressed();
    else
        moveTaskToBack(true);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dist = findViewById(R.id.distancetext);
    time = findViewById(R.id.timetext);
    speed = findViewById(R.id.speedtext);
    disttext = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    timetext = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);

    preferences2 = getSharedPreferences(Einstellungen.SHARED_PREFERENCES2, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int size = preferences2.getInt(Einstellungen.SELECTED_COLOR2, 0);
    speed.setTextSize(size);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(Einstellungen.SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int color = preferences.getInt(Einstellungen.SELECTED_COLOR, Color.WHITE);
    speed.setTextColor(color);
    time.setTextColor(color);
    dist.setTextColor(color);
    timetext.setTextColor(color);
    disttext.setTextColor(color);
    start();
    init();
}

        public void start() {
            checkGps();
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                return;
            }


            if (status == false)
                bindService();
            locate = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            locate.setIndeterminate(true);
            locate.setCancelable(false);
            locate.setMessage("searching gps");
            locate.show();
        }

void checkGps() {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


        showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
    }
}

private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("please activate your gps")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("activate gps",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        }
                    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

**LocationServices**

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements
    LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 2;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mCurrentLocation, lStart, lEnd;
static double distance = 0;
double speed;


private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return mBinder;
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
    }
}


protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
    distance = 0;
}

public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    MainActivity.locate.dismiss();
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    if (lStart == null) {
        lStart = mCurrentLocation;
        lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
    } else
        lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
    updateUI();
    speed = location.getSpeed() * 18 / 5;

}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

    public LocationService getService() {
        return LocationService.this;
    }


}

private void updateUI() {
    if (MainActivity.p == 0) {
        distance = distance + (lStart.distanceTo(lEnd) / 1000.00);
        MainActivity.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long diff = MainActivity.endTime - MainActivity.startTime;
        diff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
        MainActivity.time.setText(" " + diff + " min");
        if (speed > 0.0)
            MainActivity.speed.setText(" " + new DecimalFormat("#").format(speed) + " ");
        else
            MainActivity.speed.setText("0");

        MainActivity.dist.setText(" " + new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(distance) + " km");

        lStart = lEnd;

    }

}

public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    stopLocationUpdates();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    lStart = null;
    lEnd = null;
    distance = 0;
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

}

**Settings**

```
public class Einstellungen extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] names2 = {"Small", "Normal", "Big"};
String[] des2 = {"Small", "Normal", "Big"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
Spinner spinner2;
TextView description2;
public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES2 = "SHARED_PREDS2";
public static final String SELECTED_COLOR2 = "SELECTED_COLOR2";
public SharedPreferences preferences2;
public static final String SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION2 = "SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION2";

String[] names = {"White", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Gray", "Cyan", "Magenta"};
String[] des = {"White", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Gray", "Cyan", "Magenta"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner spinner;
TextView description;
public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SHARED_PREFS";
public static final String SELECTED_COLOR = "SELECTED_COLOR";
public SharedPreferences preferences;
public static final String SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION = "SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION";
public ImageButton androidImmageButton;
public ImageButton androidImmageButton2;
public ImageButton androidImmageButton3;

public Button button;

public void init() {
    androidImmageButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    androidImmageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toy = new Intent(Einstellungen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(toy);
        }
    });
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_einstellungen);

    preferences2 = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES2, MODE_PRIVATE);
    spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    description2 = findViewById(R.id.text);
    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    int position2 = preferences2.getInt(SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION2, 0);
    spinner2.setSelection(position2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int d, long l) {
            preferences2.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION2, d).apply();
            switch (d) {
                case 0:
                    description2.setText(des2[d]);
                    preferences2.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR2, 140).apply();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    description2.setText(des2[d]);
                    preferences2.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR2, 190).apply();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    description2.setText(des[d]);
                    preferences2.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR2, 240).apply();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    description = findViewById(R.id.text);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    int position = preferences.getInt(SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION, 0);
    spinner.setSelection(position);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR_POSITION, i).apply();
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.WHITE).apply();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.BLUE).apply();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.RED).apply();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.GREEN).apply();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.YELLOW).apply();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.GRAY).apply();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.CYAN).apply();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    description.setText(des[i]);
                    preferences.edit().putInt(SELECTED_COLOR, Color.MAGENTA).apply();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    init();
}
```

}

Comment: Dumping code is IMHO not very welcome here. What have you tried to solve your problem and where have you stuck while fixing your problem?

Comment: I changed the api-Level because I thought the android version is the Problem.. but nothing changed. I dont have other solitions :/

Comment: I'm still not reviewing your code, but do other apps work? E.g. Google Maps on those devices? Do you have the required (runtime) permissions? Which Android versions are on the problematic devices 6.0+?

Comment: Yes other apps like Google maps are working. They have runtime permissions too

Comment: Yes 5. is working well.. newer versions not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164785/discussion-between-rekire-and-tailor).

Comment: A service having an updateUI function directly setting variables?  No.  Throw out everything and start from scratch, that alone makes this code unsalvagable.  I'd start with researching a basic understanding of communications with Services and what they're used for.  Hint:  there's no need to even use a service here, unless you have other activities that also need the GPS location